# How to separate format specifiers from characters with printf

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers, conversion-specifier, length-modifiers

Another way to phrase this question might be "How to end format specifiers in printf"

If I want to print microseconds in this format `100us` using the following code...

```cpp
long microseconds = 100L;
printf("%lus", microseconds);
```

only prints `100s` because the `u` is combined with the `%l` and it interprets the format specifier as an `unsigned long` instead of a `long`

Comment: `%l` is not a complete format specification by itself. It might work by accident on some C libraries but it's incorrect to rely on that. Always give complete format specifications (in this case you wanted `%ld`) and you won't have this problem.

Comment: @zwol ah, noticed that after posting. The question is more in general, since I'm sure there are other cases where a conflict can occur. I'll try to find a different example

Comment: The answer for the general case is the same: all conversion specifications must end with one of the "conversion specifier" characters  (comprehensive list here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8) You will not have a conflict with subsequent text if you make sure always to do that. Also, `printf` may crash or print nonsense if you don't always do that. I can make that a proper answer later when I'm on a real computer.

Comment: @zwol I think my confusion came from not realizing that every format specifier has to end with a single conversion specifier symbol/character.  And then also mixing up some of the conversion specifiers with other modifiers. Thanks for helping me clear up my confusion!

Comment: Note the `L` in  `100L` serves little purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write

```
long microseconds = 100L;
printf("%ldus", microseconds);
```

Pay attention to that you may not use a length modifier without a conversion specifier.

Comment: ....or `%lius`.

Answer (score 1):

> How to separate format specifiers from characters with printf

If **separation** is important:

```
long microseconds = 100L;
printf("%ld" "us", microseconds);
```

Adjacent literal strings are concatenated.  The above is equivalent to `"%ldus"`.

```
// or maybe via macros
#DEFINE TIME_FMT "%ld"
#DEFINE TIME_SUFFIX "us"
...
printf(TIME_FMT TIME_SUFFIX, microseconds);
```